# $H_{\infty}$ optimization of transfer function matrix

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a two-dimensional $(2 \times 2)$ transfer function matrix like this:

$$G(s) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{xs+1} & \frac{1}{s+0.5}\\ 
 \frac{3}{s+3}& \frac{1}{ys+2}
\end{pmatrix} $$

The aim is to solve optimization problem:

$$\min_{x, y} ||G||_\infty $$

There is no built-in function to obtain $H_{\infty}$ norm of a transfer function.

How can I perform this optimization?